# D3 arc partition visualization with partial fill

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a visualization that's somewhat similar to sunburst.  It's basically a pie chart, with each partition evenly divided and where the data represents the percent fill of the partition.  Here is what I currently have with code below...

[image: a busy cat]

Each partition should be partially filled from the inner radius with the percentage of the slice filled.  Any ideas?

```
var width = 600,
  height = 600,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
  .sort(null)
  .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
  .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
  .innerRadius(function(d) { console.log("INNER: ", d.y); return 0; })
  .outerRadius(function(d) { console.log("OUTER: ", d.y, d.dy); return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });



d3.json("data.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; }) // hide inner ring
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
    .style("fill-rule", "evenodd");

});


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

Comment: I think this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305934/d3-donut-charts-of-varying-radius

Comment: They are different.  The answer in the link you provided is around adjusting inner radius, which works if you want to have many donut charts with different donut sizes, but I'm looking for a single chart that will allow me to adjust the fill of the partitions.

Comment: I guess you could use a hard radial gradient for this, but I think it will be easier to use the solution for the other question, which should produce the same end result if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

Comment: Ah, wow, ok, looking more into the solution, it makes sense.  I must of rushed through it the first time and didn't realize you can set inner/outer radius for each arc.  Thanks @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Ok, I'll close this question as a duplicate then?